# Limits for Telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, high-load

We're trying to implement telegram bot as notification tool for high load system. We're afraid of limits and bans from telegram in case of such huge amount of messages.
In official doc and FAQ I found the information about  limits such as 1 message per second or 30 messages per sec for bulk notifications.

So, have you ever tried to implement telegram bot for high load system and what restrictions did you find?
How many messages for how many users is possible to sent per 1 second (not bulk messsages, jjust personal notifications)

More info here https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#broadcasting-to-users

Now we're on analysing stage and want to know all possible limits

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you see this link

All Telegram limitations have been collected and categorized:

https://limits.tginfo.me/en

Comment: Thanks for the link! Unfortunately, we found here only 1 limitation for group chat (20 messages per sec). Hope I could find more information about limitations.